# Postgresql: round up the time to nearest 15 minute range (0,15,30,45)

Tags: sql, postgresql

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55782240/sql-python-transform-data-from-csv-and-into-table-with-different-schema-with-co/55783340?noredirect=1#comment98248534_55783340)'s answer, I have a datetime column where I do `date_time::timestamp - INTERVAL '1 HOUR'` in the select statement.

What I want to do is that, I want to create a interval of a 15 minutes range (0, 15,30,45) So, the result should be like 2019-04-21 09:00:00 or 2019-04-21 09:15:00 and so on. The result should be change to the nearest time i.e. for 00:00 to 07:29 minute will be round down to 00:00 and 07:30 to 15:00 will be round up to 15:00.This apply to 15, 30 and 45 as well

So from `2019-04-21 09:52:29` should become `2019-04-21 09:45:00` and `2019-04-21 09:52:30` should become `2019-04-21 10:00:00`

I have searched and found `date_trunc` function but I don't know how to do base on what I specific.

Thank you!

Edit: I have look at the duplicated post and some answers. I found answer that used dateadd and datediff function but these functions cannot be use with postgresql.

`select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,GETDATE()) / 15 * 15, 0)`

How can apply this to postgresql ?

Edit2: There are solutions that use a create function to round up and down but the above is quite better.

Comment: to_timestamp (round(( extract ('epoch' from (name_of_timestamp_column)) ) / (60*15) ) * (60*15) )

Comment: To always round up, in the expression of @FarahNazifa, remplace 'round' by 'ceil'.